# PHP Remove from text

Tags: php

I have text like in my database stored as sended email

```
    <style type='text/css'>
        body {background: #f2f2f2}
        .email_container {width: 700px; margin: 20px auto 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
        .email_content {width: 100%; border: #ddd 1px solid; padding: 5px 15px 5px; background: #fff}
        .logo {padding-top:6px}
    </style>

    <body>
    <div class='email_container'>
        <div class='email_content'>
            <img src='logo.png' class='logo' width='20%'/>
            <p />
Hello, welcome to my page!
```

And how can i only display text **Hello, welcome to my page!** from code like that ?

Comment: ehrm... remove the rest? help me out a bit here, because I have the feeling I don't really understand your question

Comment: That HTML code tagged as CODE was my email stored in database, i need in PHP display only text Hello, welcome to my page! from all code. @giorgio

Comment: With `strip_tags`

Comment: when there's no relevant code for a tag used, this makes the question both unclear and too broad and asking us to find/make it for you; what have you tried?

Comment: *"I have text like in my database stored as sended email"* - Why are you storing HTML in a db? HTML/PHP/MySQL are all totally different animals and should be treated as such and handled correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$htmlStr = "
        <style type='text/css'>
        body {background: #f2f2f2}
        .email_container {width: 700px; margin: 20px auto 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
        .email_content {width: 100%; border: #ddd 1px solid; padding: 5px 15px 5px; background: #fff}
        .logo {padding-top:6px}
    </style>

    <body>
    <div class='email_container'>
        <div class='email_content'>
            <img src='logo.png' class='logo' width='20%'/>
            <p />
Hello, welcome to my page!
";

// echo strip_tags($htmlStr, '<style>');
echo trim(substr(strip_tags($htmlStr, '<style>'),strpos($htmlStr, "</style>")+8)); // ----- As @Andreas mentioned this is the right one -----
```

Comment: Why do you keep the <style> tag?

Comment: It's because ```strip_tags``` can't able to filter the ```<style>``` tag.

Comment: I don't understand... I think this is the result wanted: https://3v4l.org/2cbhe , your code gives this: https://3v4l.org/o64b6

Comment: Oh no, you are right. Actually, I checked that on my browser & browser was automatically using its brain to fix the CSS part & only showing me the require LINE. Your solution is the right one.

Comment: @Andreas Please, post your answer with your version of the code.

Comment: Can't do it. The question is marked as a duplicate.

Comment: At least comment the ```strip_tags()``` version of your code. I'll be happy to upvote.

Comment: There is no point of that.. It's better if you just copy the code to your answer. Don't know how long 3v4l keeps the codes.

Comment: Thanks its work!

Answer (score 0):

php function stip_tags can help you a lot -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

or you can write your own regexp and match the needed text

BTW: <p /> is very invalid ;)